# Wordpress archive page navigation not working

Tags: wordpress, navigation, archive

Not sure why, but I can't seem to get the page navigation working in my wordpress archive template file. Wondering if someone might be able to lead me in the right direction here...

Here's the code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="pageDescriptBracket">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pdBracket.png">
    </div> <!-- pageDescriptBracket -->
    <h1>The Books</h1>
    <div class="pageDescriptSmall">
        An archive of the condominium's financial records
    </div> <!-- pageDescriptSmall -->

    <?php
      $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
      'posts_per_page' => 1)); // how many posts to show

      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
      $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <div class="entryBooks">
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

      <div class="postnav">
          <div class="alignleft"><?php posts_nav_link('','','&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
      <div class="alignright"><?php posts_nav_link('','Next Entries &raquo;','') ?></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What's it doing wrong?

Comment: It's just not showing up, at all.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the recommended usage for `posts_nav_link()`, which normally displays both the previous and next links; the second parameter should be the text for the previous link and the third parameter should be the text for the next link.

What you're doing looks like what the documentation specifically warns against under "Kubrick theme format".

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research into that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making changes to your core WP files, which will be lost when you update to the next version of WP, why not just use a plugin like [WP PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) or [TW Pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tw-pagination/)?

If you're using Wordpress SEO, then make sure you go into your wp-admin ... **SEO** >> **Titles and Metas** >> **Other** and make sure **Disable the date-based archives** is unchecked.

Comment: I tend to prefer hard-coded sites to plugins, but I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay ... I'd personally keep a changelog of all files you edit and how you edit them.  Like I intimated, many people fall into that trap of getting cute w/ the core WP files.  And then they upgrade (i.e. from 3.5 to 3.5.1) and they realize that their entire WP has changed.  It's much more stable to add solid plugins, and if you're going to make changes to core WP files, keep 'em to a minimum and keep a log.

Comment: There's a bit of a difference because I build my sites from scratch so I'm not using a theme, I'm building it as I go. Not changing core WP files, I'm writing them.